# Javascript:why the array slice method could turn nodelist or arguments to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I know the usage like:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'))
```

to turn `Nodelist` datatype to array without a parameter, but I read from the [W3CSchool](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) about the usage of `slice`, the first parameter `start` is required:

> start Required. An integer that specifies where to start the selection
>   (The first element has an index of 0). Use negative numbers to select
>   from the end of an array

so without a parameter and call that method is just OK? Why this could success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's play a game of follow the breadcrumbs

In the es5 spec,

1. [`Array.prototype.slice(start, end)`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.10)

   > Let `relativeStart` be `ToInteger(start)`
2. [`ToInteger`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.4)

   > 1. Let `number` be the result of calling `ToNumber` on the input argument
3. [`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3)

   > `Undefined` transforms to `NaN`
4. Backtrack `ToInteger`

   > 2. If `number` is `NaN`, return `+0`.

So even though it is not explicitly stated to be optional, if `start` is *undefined*, it becomes `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) than [w3cschools/fools](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Yes, what you are doing is correct, see the "Array-like objects" section of:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: +1 for MDN and OP is right `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'))` should not work (it does in FF) because according to the documentation the begin parameter is not optional so you should use `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'),0)` You could introduce quirks leaving the begin parameter out like with an array sort function that returns true or false, works in FF but not in Chrome or Safari.

Comment: @HMR I think you'll find you can leave out the first parameter in _Chrome_, too. `Array.prototype.slice.call({length:2}); // [undefined × 2]`

Comment: @PaulS. Your answer explains why it works (probably in all browsers) but I think it would be best to pass the begin parameter. The fact that it works is because of the browser implementation of converting undefined into a number but when properly implemented slice should trow an error (missing mandatory parameter). It's unlikely the implementation will change because it'll probably break a lot of scripts but you never know.

Comment: @HMR where does it say it is a "mandatory parameter" anywhere in the spec? As you can plainly see, the per-spec algorithm never says to throw an exception, unlike other algorithms such as [`Array.prototype.every`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.16) where it has `4. If IsCallable(callbackfn) is false, throw a TypeError exception.`

Comment: @PaulS. I thought the syntax of the documentation was somefunction(mandatory[,optional]) But I guess looking at the es5 documentation a little more they'll throw in the brackets or leave it out whenever they feel like it.